# is clock_gettime() call atomic?

Tags: c, linux, clock

i use timespec structure in multi-threaded code - one thread calls `clock_gettime()` to fill in the global timespec structure, the other - reads this structure. Question: is `clock_gettime()` call atomic or I have to use mutex?

Comment: The concept of a global `timespec` is interesting, as the value is, obviously, obsolete as soon as the time was obtained ;) Anyway, why not get the time on a *different* structure and the atomically swap the global pointer to point to the last value. Much lighter than a mutex.

Comment: @RemusRusanu: A simple RCU, I presume?

Comment: The behavior of `clock_gettime` is defined by POSIX. It says nothing about atomicity, so if it _happens to be_ atomic on your computer, that's coincidence (or as one might say: "implementation detail"). I very much doubt it is atomic, though. Neither is this usually needed, nor is it easy and straightforward to do given _two_ `long int` values in the struct (you'd have to do some weird hack like move them into a SSE register first, and then write that one to memory).

Comment: With that in mind, I'd just make an array of two `timespec` structures (or rather somewhat bigger structures with some extra padding so they land on difference cache lines), and an integer used as index, which one can flip between 0 and 1 using `__sync_fetch_and_xor` or whatever the C11 equivalent is (if whatever you use supports memory models, use "release").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be very surprised if it was, though I can't find any reference on it. Calling `clock_gettime` is nothing but calling a library function. So if I'm right, you definitely need a mutex to ensure that another thread is not reading the `struct timespec` while `clock_gettime` et reading it.

Answer (score 0):

The `clock_gettime` man page - http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime - doesn't say it's atomic so you've no reasonable expectation of it being atomic, and the structure contains two `long`s so you've no particularly sound basis to even hope.  Still, if your hardware supports atomic operations on 64-bit values then rather than fiddle with pointers as Remus suggests, or use a mutex, you *could* populate another `timespec` then atomically copy it over your global one, but if your hardware doesn't guarantee memory updates are visible across cores and CPUs (e.g. recent Intel/AMD hardware does, but at least 10 years ago when I cared the UltraSparc's didn't) then you'll need an explicit memory barrier (i.e. some machine code injected into your program - possibly using a compiler- or system-provider "builtin" function) to ensure visibility; a mutex implementation will already handle that for you.